# ¿Cómo corregir advertencia React.createFactory() is deprecated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy desarrollando una app con React. Y al iniciarla siempre veo en la consola la advertencia: "react.development.js:315 Warning: React.createFactory() is deprecated and will be removed in a future major release. Consider using JSX or use React.createElement() directly instead."

Me gustaría sber como corregir esto para remover la advertencia. Gracias de antemano

Comment: En páginas donde se menciona el error, hablan de `recompose` como el culpable de eso, quizás puedas empezar por eso.

Comment: Además encontré esto que te puede ayudar -> https://es.reactjs.org/warnings/legacy-factories.html

Comment: Sí, también vi eso. Pero me lleva a la duda de que es un error en alguna dependencia. Entonces debería actualizar esa dependencia o alguna otra?

Comment: No tienes `recompose` tu ??

Comment: Sí, lo tengo. Intentaré actualizarlo para ver si eso soluciona la advertencia

Comment: Revisa en páginas ese error, en algunas dicen como solucionarlo, pero hay 2 o 3 soluciones diferentes a probar